# Disabling cookies in Android browser not working

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, mobile-safari

I am running Android Honeycomb 3.2.1 and I am having trouble getting the browser to stop accepting cookies. I have the following code:

first.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setCookie('testing','test cookie',365);
            window.location.href = 'second.html';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

second.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var temp = getCookie('testing');
            alert(temp);
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

cookie.js:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";     expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now if I shut off cookies and visit first.html on any of my desktop browsers, I get redirected and get an alert that says null as expected.

If I turn on my cookies and visit first.html on any of my desktop browsers, I get redirected and get an alert that says "test cookie" as expected.

Now if I run this on my Android tablet with cookies disabled it always returns "test cookie" in an alert. It doesn't matter if I have cookies on or off. I have tried changing the settings, removing the cookies and cache, restarting the browser and even restarted the tablet and all with the same results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same problem in 4.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

How about checking if cookies are enabled before returning the cookie:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    if(navigator.cookieEnabled) {
      var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
      for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
      {
          x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
          y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
          x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
          if (x==c_name)
          {
              return unescape(y);
          }
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```